# Saving compilation options

Tags: unix, libraries

Suppose a library have been configured and compiled into `/opt/name/` by root. Is there a way for me to see the options passed to `./configure` when the program was first compiled and installed (short of finding the `config.log`)?

If not, is there a utility to automatically store configuration logs?

Answer (score 0):

Check the `Makefile` file.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configure_script

Comment: But the makefile is stored in the same directory as the source files, and there is no way to know where that is, and if that directory still exists